# Regular expression to catch all possibilities?

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

My input is a genetic data that looks like this:

```
SNP       VALUE
rs123456  A/G
rs345353  del/CTT
rs343524  T
rs243224  T/del
....
```

Without getting deeply into genetics, all of us have 2 alleles (mom and dad) so if you have single value without "/" (A/C/G/T/del/CTT) that means both alleles are the same, if not, there is slash "/" to show they are different.

Long story short, I need to find known patterns of the SNP's but I understand that there are a lot of possibilities (if number of / (slashed) values is large).

I have already built regular expression like this: `[A|C|G|T|del|CTT]`.

A/G = G/A so I need to match all possibilities.

Is there any function or logic that can help me to do this? Please advise.

P.S

Adding more info:

The expected output is all possible variants of the values for example:

```
rs123 = A/G, rs456 = T/C, rs789 = CTT: 
Option 1: A T CTT; 
Option 2: A C CTT; 
Option 3: G T CTT; 
Option 4: G C CTT;
```

but if I have more then 2 / I want to get all the options.

Comment: Could you provide the expected output? Also consider adding a bigger data example.

Comment: So what's your expected output and could you provide sample input that would cover all bases (that is sample input for multiple cases such as the ones you've mentioned are possibilities). Doing so will help us properly assist you.

Comment: I guess you need to split by `/`, then `sort`, and `paste` back together

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, the expected output is all possible variants of the values for example:
rs123 = A/G, rs456 = T/C, rs789 = CTT:
Option 1: A T CTT;
Option 2: A C CTT;
Option 3: G T CTT;
Option 4: G C CTT;
but if I have more then 2 / I want to get all the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are after this:

```
df = data.frame(SNP = c("rs123456",  "rs345353", "rs343524" ,"rs243224"),
                value = c("A/G", "del/CTT", "T", "T/del"), stringsAsFactors = F)

expand.grid(strsplit(df$value, "/"))
#output
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1    A  del    T    T
2    G  del    T    T
3    A  CTT    T    T
4    G  CTT    T    T
5    A  del    T  del
6    G  del    T  del
7    A  CTT    T  del
8    G  CTT    T  del
```

or if a string is required per combination

```
apply(expand.grid(strsplit(df$value, "/")), 1, paste, collapse = " ")
#output
[1] "A del T T"   "G del T T"   "A CTT T T"   "G CTT T T"   "A del T del" "G del T del"
[7] "A CTT T del" "G CTT T del"
```

or:

```
do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(strsplit(df$value, "/")), sep=" "))
```

Comment: Bravo! Thanks!
I am also looking for a regex solution.